# How do you switch single quotes to double quotes using to_tsv() when dealing with a column of lists?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: "text", 1: [["foo", "bar"]]})
df
      0           1
0  text  [foo, bar]
```

And I write the df out to a tsv file like this

```
df.to_csv('test.tsv',sep="\t",index=False,header=None, doublequote=True)
```

The tsv file looks like this

```
text    ['foo', 'bar']
```

How do I ensure there are double quotes around my list items and make test.tsv look like this?

```
text    ["foo", "bar"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `json.dumps`

```
import json
df[1]=df[1].map(json.dumps)
```

Then

```
df.to_csv('test.tsv', sep="\t", index=False, header=None, doublequote=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: That creates a tsv that looks like this

text "[""foo"", ""bar""]"

Comment: however adding quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE does the trick :)